# Differences between ActiveRecord and Repository when generating JPA entity from a database schema using Spring Roo?

Tags: jpa, activerecord, repository, spring-roo, dbref

As Spring Roo guide [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-roo/reference/html/base-dbre.html) to do DBRE on a schema, we have the below command to generate the entities and theirs related files.

We there can choose between taking the argument --activerecord or --repository; choosing the later will ignore the first.

My question is what are the differences between the two?

> roo> **database reverse engineer** --schema DbSchemaName --package ~.domain **--activeRecord
>   --repository** 
>                                  --service --testAutomatically --enableViews 
>                                  --includeTables --excludeTables 
>                                  --includeNonPortableAttributes 
>                                  --disableVersionFields --disableGeneratedIdentifiers
>
> Use the **--activeRecord** option to create 'Active Record' entities
>   (default if not specified).
>
> Use the **--repository** option to create Spring Data JPA Repositories for
>   each entity. If specified as true, the --activeRecord option is
>   ignored.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Roo talk about those patterns at http://docs.spring.io/spring-roo/docs/1.3.1.RC1/reference/html/base-layers.html#d4e1932

### [Active Record Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern)

- The active record pattern is an approach to accessing data in a
  database. A database table or view is wrapped into a class. Thus, an
  object instance is tied to a single row in the table.
- Example: persist new instance (create new row):

  > ```
  > Part part = new Part();
  > part.name = "Sample part";
  > part.price = 123.45;
  > part.save();
  > ```

### [Repository pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html)

- A Repository mediates between the domain and data mapping layers, acting like an in-memory domain object collection. Conceptually, a Repository encapsulates the set of objects persisted in a data store and the operations performed over them, providing a more object-oriented view of the persistence layer. Repository also supports the objective of achieving a clean separation and one-way dependency between the domain and data mapping layers.
- Example: persist new instance (create new row):

  > ```
  > Part part = new Part(); 
  > part.name = "Sample part"; 
  > part.price = 123.45; 
  >
  > //RepositoryFactorySupport ;
  > factory = ...; // Instantiate factory here or similar PartRepository 
  > repository = factory.getRepository(PartRepository.class); 
  > repository.save(part);
  > ```

Comment: Please summay or quote the related content in your answer to get verified and accepted.

Comment: Roo ref guide doesn't clarify the concepts, I improved my answer.

Comment: Thanks for listing specific link. My OP ask for the differences and if you have read your suggested links, please drop us here your summary on the differences you found. Thank you!

Comment: I need more to understand... though it is very much better now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Nam, could you close the question as answered? Thanks